# Making a Circle in using Math nodes

Tags: math, geometry, nodes, blender, procedural

I tried to make a **circle** using *Math Nodes* in Blender Shader Editor on a default **Plane**. A default **Plane** has dimensions of [2 m * 2 m]. I used the standard equation

> (x-g)^2 + (y-h)^2 - r^2 = 0

But the circle formed exceeds the **Plane** when I use the value (1,1) for (g,h). But when I use (0.5,0.5) for (g,h) I get the desired result.

[image]

Mathematically, shouldn't the top right corner of the **Plane** be (2,2) while the centre of the **Plane** be (1,1).
Please help me.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [blender.stackexchange.com](https://blender.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @r3mainer Thanks for letting me know about it. I did not know that (https://blender.stackexchange.com) existed. I will make sure to post further queries over there.

Answer (score 1):

With the shown setup your center is at 0.5,0.5 and the diameter is 1.
That does get you a circle spanning the 0..1/0..1 coordinate range of a texture.

Try using a 4x4 plane. It probably will give you an insight:
The texture coordinates and the object/vertex coordinates are different.